# Ubuntu 15.10 64 is very slow on Four Core i7 16GB of Ram

Tags: dell, performance, 15.10

I'm very new to Ubuntu.
I came from a Macbook pro to a Dell Latitude E74400 i7 16Gb of ram.

Ubuntu is terribly slow even if I reinstall it. 
It laggs when I work with it, opening multiple windows.

The newest firefox lags alot with only two tabs open.

Intellij 15 is also lagging.

I have checked my driver support, and it says it is using intel drivers.

I always update the system.

Nothing new is running in the background.

Comment: I have the same core i7 and 16GB of RAM, but Ubuntu is very slow only when I perform file operations. It runs smoothly the rest of the time.

Comment: I switched to windows 10 and it runs a lot a lot faster with everything I do.

Comment: I have the same issue.. any ideas ?

Comment: Found the solution for my issue. I needed to disable "speed step" feature in BIOS. Please read the following blog for more information http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/fixed-my-i7-intel-dell-laptop-is-ridiculously-slow/